# Keyframe Animation on Div Height Affecting Bottom

Tags: css, height, css-animations, keyframe

I'm working on a simple CSS animation that looks like a horizontal sound visualizer. As I've been working on the first three horizontal bars I've noticed that when animating the div's height, only the bottom is affected.

What would be the work around to reverse this animation effect?

CSS:

```css
body{
  background-color: #283739;
}
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10em auto;
}
@keyframes line {
  50% {height: 120px}
}
@keyframes line2 {
  50% {height: 122px}
}
@keyframes line3 {
  50% {height: 123px}
}
.box1{
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line 0.7s linear 0s infinite;
}
.box2{
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #A9C52F;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line2 0.5s linear 0s infinite;
}
.box3{
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line3 0.8s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

Here is the [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/jonahbutler/pen/PbZPwx?editors=1100#0) link.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If yes, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

**Height Animation:** (your original code)

In the code that you've given in question you are animating the `height` of an element. When height is animated by default the element would grow from top to bottom because of how the document flows.

In order to achieve the reverse effect, you have to position the `div[class^="box"]` (all `div` elements whose class starts with `box`) elements absolutely with respect to the parent. When it is done, all the height changes will grow from bottom up and thus you'll end up getting the reverse effect.

Below is an extract of the properties that I had added (only those that I had added, refer to the snippet for full demo):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
div[class^="box"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box1 {
  left: 0px;
}
.box2 {
  left: 20px;
}
.box3 {
  left: 40px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #283739;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10em auto;
}
@keyframes line {
  50% {
    height: 120px
  }
}
@keyframes line2 {
  50% {
    height: 122px
  }
}
@keyframes line3 {
  50% {
    height: 123px
  }
}
div[class^="box"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box1 {
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line 0.7s linear 0s infinite;
}
.box2 {
  left: 20px;
  background-color: #A9C52F;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line2 0.5s linear 0s infinite;
}
.box3 {
  left: 40px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line3 0.8s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

---

**ScaleY Transform Animation:** (alternate, less performance intensive approach)

Another way to produce this effect would be by using CSS `scaleY` transforms. Here there is no need to use `position`, we can set `transform-origin` as `bottom` to indicate that the scaleY (that is scale the height) should happen with the bottom point being fixed.

```css
@keyframes line {
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1.2);
  }
}
@keyframes line2 {
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1.22);
  }
}
@keyframes line3 {
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1.23);
  }
}
div[class^="box"] {
  float: left;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #283739;
}
.container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10em auto;
}
@keyframes line {
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1.2);
  }
}
@keyframes line2 {
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1.22);
  }
}
@keyframes line3 {
  50% {
    transform: scaleY(1.23);
  }
}
div[class^="box"] {
  float: left;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line 0.7s linear 0s infinite;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: #A9C52F;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line2 0.5s linear 0s infinite;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #001F39;
  animation: line3 0.8s linear 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```